# RewriteRule not working for directories with starting and trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory, rewriting

I have an URL like these:

```
http://domain.com/database/movie/jurassic-park.1224.html
http://domain.com/artist/bruno-mars.104.html
```

I tried to resolve these URLs with the following RewriteRules, but they don't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/movie\/(.*)\.(.*)\.html$ ./index.php?area=movies&id=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/artist\/(.*)\.(.*)\.html$ ./index.php?area=people&id=$2 [QSA]
```

Who can help me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule movie/(.+?)\.(\d+)\.html$ index.php?area=movies&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule artist/(.+?)\.(\d+)\.html$ index.php?area=people&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```